# How can I render 100 different images in 100 different pages with their own URL. I'm using react and next js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

```
{

  "image_location": "fans/mdf-1.png",

  "image_id": "mdf-1",

  "image_name": "Product 1"

},

{

  "image_location": "fans/mdf-2.png",

  "image_id": "mdf-2",

  "image_name": "Product 2"

}
```

]
}

Please ask for more info if needed.

Thanks in advance.

I just have 1 page with a image. Need 100 more with their own url.

I have come up with a temporary solution which works, but it is not good.

const pathname = window.location.pathname // Get the pathname of the current URL

const id = pathname.substring(1) // Remove the first character '/' from the pathname to get the id
const imageurl = `https://www.example.com/demo/fans/${id}.png`
.
.
.

.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you can use dynamic routing with nextJs,
for example pages/images/[imageName] and based on the imageName you can render you image.

check nextJs doc : https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/dynamic-routes

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. But can I do this without any backend code? in react only

Comment: yeah you can do it without backend code.

Comment: Please tell me how.

Comment: okay let's say that all your images are located in the public directory :
/public
   -image1.png
   -image2.png
   ....

and your route is like that : www.example.com/images/[imageName]
so if a user enter this link: www.example.com/images/image1
you can add this code into your component 
  const router = useRouter()
  const { imageName} = router.query

and then you can show the image in <img /> element like this
<img src=`/${imageName}.png` />